# How can people use licensed images on Facebook pages without any copyright issue?

Tags: copyright, licensing, facebook, instagram

I have seen popular Facebook Pages with millions of followers like
[Eric's Creamy Memes](https://m.facebook.com/EricsCreamyMeme/), [Meme Supreme](https://m.facebook.com/memesupremeofficial/), [Wholesome Memes](https://m.facebook.com/wholesomememe/), [Lean Mean Saucy Memes](https://m.facebook.com/leanmeansaucymemes/), [Dankland](https://m.facebook.com/dankland/), that post images that don't belong to public domain.

Some of the images even have a Shutterstock watermark on them - like [this](https://www.facebook.com/dankland/photos/a.1040374136039782.1073741828.1038550562888806/1397508510326341/?type=3&theater) one.

The same can be said for hundreds of such FB/Twitter/Instagram accounts

**Why don't they get any copyright strikes? Why doesn't Facebook takes these posts/pages down?**

Answer (score 4):

You can't, legally, but as you note, the practice is so pervasive that it's unlikely that you'll get in any particular financial trouble. From a moral and ethical point of view, though, please don't.

Facebook, Pinterest, and other social media sharing sites don't aggressively take them down because... it's to their advantage to not to. Unlike movies and and music, there's no gigantic, well-funded legal organization forcing takedowns for when some photographer's work is misappropriated.

Comment: If Shutterstock tries to (hell bent), then can they take out any money from the FB page owner.? @mattdm

Comment: @AyushSrivastava Theoretically, yes.

Comment: https://thenextweb.com/facebook/2012/10/05/facebook-confirms-it-shut-down-the-cool-hunters-facebook-page-over-copyright-infringement/

Comment: Yeah, so, they did that one time in 2012.....

Comment: This is drifting pretty far away from being a photography question. From a photographers'-rights point of view, the answer is pretty clear.

Comment: note that it could well be that some of those sites paid Shutterstock for the use - you wouldn't know or see that.

Comment: @Aganju Well, they would be unlikely to have a big watermark in that case.